# Operator precedence in selectors

Tags: jquery, operator-precedence

When I write:

```
$(tableElement).find("thead input,img")
```

Will jQuery match **inputs inside theads** and also **images**?

Or will it match **inputs inside theads** and also **images inside theads**?

More general, what is the operator precedence in jQuery selectors? I could not find it anywhere.

**Update:**

Given the precedence, can I use parenthesis, or some other way to change it inside the selector string?

When I wrote precedence, I was talking about the precedence at which the selector string operators are parsed by jQuery, not anything about which elements are included first in the resulting jQuery collection.

Comment: `,` separates selectors. `thead input` is a selector and `img` is a selector. Have a look at the CSS spec, it makes it very clear what a selector is: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/ .

Comment: **1.** There's no precedence here. **2.** What exactly would you like to change it to?

Comment: ...and why is it a downvoted question?? What is not clear here??

Comment: *"Given the precedence, can I use parenthesis, or some other way to change it inside the selector string?"* CSS doesn't have such a feature. Other "higher level" languages such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-rules) do. Since jQuery uses CSS selectors, it doesn't offer that either. But you could do `$(tableElement).find("thead").find("input,img")` instead.

Comment: @Praveen, in the end, I would like to use the selector "thead (input,img)" to say jquery I want imgs and inputs inside theads

Comment: @EduardoPoço Got your point mate. What you need to do is, see my updated answer.

Comment: @EduardoPoço Use `$(tableElement).find("thead").find("input, img")`...

Comment: @Felix so, the only way is to combine jQuery .find() and .add() to achieve general results, is that it? I was thinking it would be easier if the selector string has support for that

Comment: @EduardoPoço You can also use `.add()`, but not sure how to do. I  gave you a different solution.

Comment: You don't need `.add()`. You could also do `$(tableElement).find("thead input, thead img")`.

Comment: Do you know how CSS Selectors work?

Comment: Okay, to answer your latest question, there's **no particular order**. It's totally unordered and selects everything.

Comment: I think the word "precedence" made everyone think I have no idea how css and jQuery selectors work... I was just asking how the operators " " (blank space) and , (comma) generate the final query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector is totally clear. You are asking it to find:

```
tableElement    // The table element's
  thead input   // inputs under thead of table element and
  img           // images under the table element
```

This is like:

```
.tableElement thead input,
.tableElement img {
}
```

It selects the images under the table element and inputs under the thead, which is under the table element. I am not sure what's the precedence here.

---

If you want something like both under the same parent, you need to use:

```
$(tableElement).find("thead").find("input, img")
$(tableElement).find("thead input, thead img")
```

The above will translate to:

```
.tableElement thead input,
.tableElement thead img {
}
```

This code will get both the `img` and `input` inside the `thead` present under the `tableElement`.

---

> *When I wrote precedence, I was talking about the precedence at which the selector string operators are parsed by jQuery, not anything about which elements are included first in the resulting jQuery collection.*

Okay, to answer your latest question, there's **no particular order**. It's totally unordered and selects everything. jQuery just follows the CSS selector. It doesn't have any particular parsing order. Internally, everything is a `querySelectorAll()` and looping.

Comment: I guess the OP wondered whether `thead input,img` means something like `thead (input,img)`, i.e. `thead input, thead img`, or `(thead input), (img)`.

Comment: @FelixKling That's what I explained with an example of CSS. Isn't it clear?

Comment: Just providing clarification for your "I am not sure what's the precedence here." statement :) (your answer is clear)

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks bro! `:)`

Comment: Maybe I just misunderstood that sentence then :)

Comment: @FelixKling Could be. Happy New Year, I gave you a request in LinkedIn, BTW... `:D`

Comment: Happy New Year to you too! I'm not really using LinkedIn but I'll take a look ;) Take care!

Comment: OK, not really a hot question, sorry if it grew out of control. Thx to all! Happy new Year!

Comment: @EduardoPoço Happy New Year boss! `:D`

Answer (score 1):

In general - a comma in jQuery is a separator.

Every part of the string is evaluated alone, and then combined, so in your example - you are looking for `thead input` **AND** `img` **INSIDE** `$(tableElement)`.

As for the precedence - they will return in their place inside the `DOM`.